# Why am i getting `'str' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the indices where the `Student` column is containing `Yes`. The snippet below is my trial but no luck and throwing `'str' object has no attribute 'astype'` error.

```
  rule=lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower.contains('Yes')
  yesindex = teaching.loc[teaching['Students'].apply(rule)].index
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? How can I possibly solve it?

Comment: Evidentially ‘x’ is already a ‘str’ datatype.  Drop the astype().str functions and try again.  Additionally, ‘lower’ should be ‘lower()’.  (Sorry for poor formatting, phone doesn’t have backticks.)

Comment: We don't have enough information. Please provide an example of your "deliveries" data structure, but I'd imagine "x" is a `str` and not the data type you think it is, thus `astype` is not a valid method.

Comment: cause ```x``` is already a string. you dont need to cascade here

Comment: The string attribute does not have the 'astype' attribute.
You are trying to access an x.astype property, but x is a string value.
Example:
name: str
name = 'name'
name.astype.

Comment: @all_commenters I truly wonder why do so many people answer questions in comments lately? Even the tooltip of the *add a comment* link you click on tells you not to.

Comment: @S3DEV I recommend you update your iPhone then, say [iOS 4 or newer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133674). ;-)

Comment: `astype` only works for numpy arrays and pandas Series.  But your `apply` is passing elements of a Series to  `rule`.  In `pandas` columns with strings are object dtype, and the elements are strings.  `lambda x: x.lower.contains('Yes')` might be enough.

Comment: @S3DEV, I use the `hackers keyboard` on Android for SO friendly formatting.  @amain, I'm as guilty as any.  But my comments are short, quick, tentative, and often written on my phone.  My answers usually have working code, and more explanations - and hence much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by other comments probably you Students column is already as type string. If you want to get it do like this:

```
yesindex = deliveries.loc[deliveries['Students'].str.contains('Yes') == True].index
```

or if you want to match with lower case:

```
yesdindex = deliveries.loc[deliveries['Students'].str.lower().str.contains('yes') == True].index
```

Comment: ‘== True’ is redundant.

Comment: @S3DEV if by any chance the `"Students"` column contains Nan values, without `"== True"` it will through a ValueError  `Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`

Comment: Then the data should be cleaned first.